# security token invalid exception from aws dynamodb- .net core sdk

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-sts, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to insert records in dynamodb using AWS .NET core SDK, but I am getting following exception:

> The security token included in the request is invalid.

Please find below the steps I have done to connect it:

1. Created a new access key in IAM.
2. downloaded access key and secret key locally.
3. created a file name credentials in C:/users//.aws/
4. Added following code to the file (removed credentials for security purpose)

   `[default]
      aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
5. Added following code to appsettings.json file:

   `"AWS":{
   "Region": "ap-south-1",
   "Profile": "default"}`
6. in startup.cs, ConfigureServices method I have added following code:
   `services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
   services.AddAWSService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();`
7. When I execute my code using following piece for code, I receive exception "The security token included in the request is invalid"
8. I have also tried the getting accesskey and secret key from appsettings.json
   `"AWS": {
   "Region": "ap-south-1",
   "AccessKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "SecretKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   }`
9. And Setting these credentials in environment variables in startup.cs file

`services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());

            services.AddMvc();
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", Configuration["AWS:AccessKey"]);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", Configuration["AWS:SecretKey"]);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_REGION", Configuration["AWS:Region"]);
            services.AddAWSService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();`

10. I still get the same exception, please find the stack trace below:

> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.cs:line 60
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 212
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.d__5`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 104
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.d__7`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line 98
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.d__10`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 153
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\ErrorCallbackHandler.cs:line 58
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.d__1`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at DataAccess.Implementation.TrainerAccess.d__6.MoveNext() in D:.Net Projects\TraninerExchange\proj\TXApi\DataAccess\Implementation\TrainerAccess.cs:line 47

Can someone help me with this problem?

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here, verify your access key ID & secret access key for selected profile in AWS Explorer. Because of false credential in profile this issue is created. or if you don't need profile any more than remove it.